# Gravity Forms Post Creation : Assign random authors for new posts

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

As the title says, I have Gravity forms wordpress plugin. And I want make a form to create posts for submissions.
There is field setting for assign author for new submission but I have 15 authors and want new posts assign to them randomly.
Currently I only can set one author for new posts. How can I make it random?

Sorry for beginner question, I had a lot search in google and nothing found.